# How to configure videos from Google Drive embedded on Google Sites to auto-start and loop?

Tags: google, html, video, embed, google-sites

I have studied the methods to embed a video file into a Google site using the Embed Gadget. There is documentation about the case when the video is from YouTube. In this case, in the iframe clause we can add `?autoplay=1&loop=1`. This causes an auto start and when the end of the video is reached, it starts over again.

The problem however is that the loop instruction is ignored when the video is not from YouTube but from our own Google Drive. The reason I want the video to be loaded from the Google Drive is video quality. The conversion to YouTube results in an object which is much less sharp and clear.

So, why does the loop parameter not work when the source is different? Do I have to use a different syntax? (I also tried several approaches by modifying the resulting html code but I never was successful.)

Here the code I use today:

```
<iframe 
src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMbHV3U3phZlVSdTQ/preview?loop=1&autoplay=1" width="1100" height="278">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they are attempting to support `?autoplay=1` but are failing at that:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMbHV3U3phZlVSdTQ/preview opens the video in a paused state
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMbHV3U3phZlVSdTQ/preview?foo=bar does the same
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMbHV3U3phZlVSdTQ/preview?autoplay=1 crashes with an error:
  `Uncaught TypeError: gapi.loaded_0 is not a function at cb=gapi.loaded_0:1`

Answer (score 0):

Somebody asked [this question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/8m2OGDWbepQ) on the Google product forums.   It looks like Google Drive uses a different parameter for auto play:  `start=1`  So to get auto play to work you would change your code to:

```
<iframe 
src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMbHV3U3phZlVSdTQ/preview?start=1" width="1100" height="278">
</iframe>
```

I was unable to find any parameter for looping with Google drive hosted video.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? `start` parameter appears to have no effect

Comment: If Google removed that functionality, the answer to the question is likely to be "it can't be done".